# "Success false" in Google Captcha implementation

Tags: php, recaptcha

Again I came up with new google captcha question.
I have a view file with the following code :

```
     <p>
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="MY_SITE_KEY"></div>
     </p>
```

Above code obviously under form element.
And after that,
In my controller, I am writing this as follows,

```
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {

        $recaptchaResponse = trim($this->input->post('g-recaptcha-response'));
        $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
        $data = array(
            'secret' => 'MY_SECRET_KEY',
            'response' => $recaptchaResponse
        );
        $options = array(
            'http' => array (
                'method' => 'POST',
                'content' => http_build_query($data)
            )
        );
        $context  = stream_context_create($options);
        $verify = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
        $captcha_success=json_decode($verify);
        #echo "<pre>"; print_r($captcha_success);die;
        if ($captcha_success->success==false) {
            echo "<p>You are a bot! Go away!</p>";
        } else if ($captcha_success->success==true) {
            echo "<p>You are not not a bot!</p>";
        } 
        die;
    }
```

But still it is not working form me.

Actually, I have registered my localhost url with Google account and I have different secret key and site key for the local and for the live one. But when I tried to use captcha, both live and local gives me same json output as the following one.

```
 {
   "success": false,
   "error-codes": [
   "missing-input-response"
   ]
 }
```

Please suggest, how to overcome with this.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting the error message, missing-input-response, because you are not passing the parameter "response" correctly.

Can you update your question with your code you are using for the call to the captcha API?

Comment: Hi, thank You for the reply. Please have a look on my updated edit

Comment: Thanks for that. I can't see anything obviously wrong with your code.
If you add `echo $this->input->post('g-recaptcha-response');` does the response look valid?  it may be that the response is getting XSS filtered by  $this->input->post();

Comment: Yes, It is looking valid too.
Cant understand where am I getting wrong.
I have stuck in it since 6 to 7 hours.Didnt get any solution over it

Comment: Can you try
`$recaptchaResponse = $this->input->post('g-recaptcha-response',FALSE);`

Comment: What about if you change it to this
`$recaptchaResponse = $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]; `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150955/discussion-between-simondarke-and-punam).